# javascript: search node in xml and get array from that node

Tags: javascript, xml

I am quite new in javascript and webcoding. I have a simple task...one can find many threads on this...but nevertheless I cannot make it run...I think I am just failing to see the wood for trees. Too much new stuff for me...

I made an Https request to read an xml file looking like below example. It is defining various column layouts for some table. I want to find the layout for a given name,for instance test2, and loop over its columns to create table...
That is:

`select layout where name = test2;
createTable(id, label, width);`

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <layout>
        <name>test</name>
        <columns>
            <column>
                <id>col_order1</id>
                <label>ORDER</label>
                <width>100px</width>
            </column>
            <column>
                <id>col_model</id>
                <label>MODEL</label>
                <width>100px</width>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </layout>
    <layout>
        <name>test2</name>
        <columns>
            <column>
                <id>col_order2</id>
                <label>ORDER</label>
                <width>100px</width>
            </column>
            <column>
                <id>col_model</id>
                <label>MODEL</label>
                <width>100px</width>
            </column>
        </columns>
    </layout>   
</root>
```

Can anbody guide me the way?
By the way: if anybody got an idea for a better xml structure: please let me know

Comment: If you want to learn the whole thing, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) tutorial should help you get started.

Comment: I would suggest using JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) is probably what you´re looking for. This gives you a JSON Object reflecting your XML:

```
var layouts = $("layout", xml).map(function() {
                    return {
                        name : $("name", this).text(),
                        columns : $("columns", this).children().map(function(){
                          return {
                            id : $("id", this).text(),
                            label : $("label", this).text(),
                            width : $("width", this).text()
                          }
                        }).get()
                      }
                }).get();
```

This gives you an Array of all layouts which allows you to work on it or look for particular properties.